# How to filter content by a specific taxonomy term when vocabulary allows multiple values?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have defined a vocabulary that allows multiple terms to be checked for a Content Type and I would like to create a View that could gather all the data from that Content Type but grouping the results by a specific term.

When I'm not applying any contextual filter, the result list should contain a group of data for every term in my vocabulary. Naturally, some of the items will appear in multiple groups because of the multiple terms scenario.

I would like to create a contextual filter for a specific term and get as a result only one of those groups. The problem is that I'm getting not only the group I expect but other groups in which some of the results have more than one term selected for the same vocabulary.

For example:

- Content type is "Dogs".
- Vocabulary is "Places".
- Taxonomy terms for "Places" are: "Kitchen", "Living room", "Garage", "Outside".

"Dogs" has a field called "Places to play with my owner" which is related to "Places" and the user can select one or more options.

I created a view that has:

- A relationship with "Places" vocabulary.
- A contextual filter that retrieves all the "Dogs" that play on each of those places when there is no specific term to filter.
- A field group using the "Places" term names.

And retrieves the following results on a URL like: `/dogs/places-to-play/`:

- Kitchen: Dog A, Dog B.
- Living Room: Dog A.
- Garage: Dog C.
- etc.

The contextual filter should receive a "Places" term name via URL like: `/dogs/places-to-play/kitchen` and the expected result would be:

- Kitchen: Dog A, Dog B.

But in my case, the results are:

- Kitchen: Dog A, Dog B.
- Living Room: Dog A.

Because "Dog A" has options "Kitchen" and "Living Room" selected in its "Places to play" field.

The question is: Is there a way to avoid getting the extra groups?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to reproduce this and am unable. Here's what I have: 1. A Content Type, *Dogs*, with a taxonomy reference field (field_places) allowing unlimited values from my *Places* vocabulary. 2. A view to show *Dogs* content. 3. The fields displayed are Title and field_places. field_places is set to be excluded from the display and it has "Display all values in the same row" **unchecked**. 4. The view is set to group content based on the rendered value of the field_places field. 5. A contextual filter on field_places (with all default settings, I didn't change anything there).

Comment: With the above, I get your expected behavior. I see content grouped by the places tags, with some titles appearing under multiple places, but no places appear more than once. I have no *Relationship* in this view since it doesn't need one as described, but even if I add a relationship to "Taxonomy term referenced from field_places", I don't see the duplicate results you mention.

Comment: I meant to also mention that if I pass a value to the contextual filter I see just the results for that tag, no other tags.

Comment: @sonfd, thanks for your reply and the time you invested replicating my example! Fortunately, reading how you did it made me realize that I didn't need the relationship to group my results in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem:

1. Removed the relationship with "Places" vocabulary and used the field "Places to play" to create the field groups, checking the "Use rendered output for a group of rows" option.
2. Unchecked the "Display all values in the same row" option for "Places to play" field.
3. Created a contextual filter for "Places to play" field to receive the value via URL.

As a result I now get what I was expecting.

Comment: I didn't need the distinct option in my view.

Comment: @sonfd, once again you are right! thank you very much. I'll edit the answer.